# WSO2 EI, How to get payload as String from Custom Class mediator

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I have created my own MediatorClass. Which has this major method:

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
    // TODO Implement your mediation logic here
    return true;
}
```

Now there is a problem. This mediator is part of REST API sequence which has Text body that I want to edit.

How it's possible to extract this Payload as String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the root element of the soap body :

```
OMElement element = (OMElement) context.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstOMChild();
```

(see [MessageContext](https://synapse.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/synapse/MessageContext.html))

Just use `element.toString()`
(see [OMElement](https://ws.apache.org/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/OMElement.html))

Comment: This works partially. It ignores <soapenv:Envelope> root tag if body is xml